# if __name__ == "__main__" condition with flask/Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was setting up a simple flask app on AWS with Elastic Beanstalk, but had a bug that would result in a timeout error when visiting the page

> ERROR: The operation timed out. The state of the environment is
>   unknown.

when running 'eb create'). Ultimately I fixed it by inserting the standard `if __name__ == '__main__':` condition before `appplication.run()` which I had originally excluded.

My question is: Why should the conditional be necessary for Elastic Beanstalk to run the application? I thought the only purpose of `__name__ == '__main__'` was so that code does not run when used as a module and I don't see why the absence of the conditional would prevent code from running.

Comment: Based on "The state of the environment is unknown" I'd say your script was executed with a delay in order to get an environment setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that adding `if __name__ == '__main__'` didn't fix anything, but it coincidentally happened to work that time.

Comment: I guess you're right - I undid the change and it ran fine again. But I'm quite sure that I hadn't changed anything else so I can't imagine what was wrong in the first place.